# How to add prev page, and next page of posts on Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add previous page and next page links on my footer, so I can limit each page to only 5 posts. I DON'T want next post, and previous post. I tried putting this in, and out of the WP loop.. but still not working!  I'm brand new to this WordPress stuff.  I already implemented next post and previous post for single.php.  I want to have previous post, and next post to be used on the index.php and other pages like /categories/, but NOT single.php.

```
  <footer id="home-footer">

            <?php posts_nav_link('','<','>'); ?>



            <div class="wrapper">
                        <p id="home-extra">You can find more articles at the <a href="/archive">archive</a>.</p>
            </div><!--end .wrapper -->

        <div class="footer-wrapper">

                <div class="projects">

                    <h1 id="projects-title">Projects</h1>

                        <ul class="footer-list">
                            <li><a href="http://dribbble.com/MatthewKosloski/projects/129666-iOS-Betas">iOS Betas</a></li>              
                        </ul>

                </div><!-- end .projects -->

                <div class="recent">

                        <h1 id="recent-title">Recent Posts</h1>


                            <ul class="footer-list">    

                                <?php
                                    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '5' );
                                    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
                                    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){

                                        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';

                                    }
                                ?>

                            </ul>

                </div><!-- end .recent -->

        <div id="dribbble"><h1 id="recent-title">What i'm working on</h1></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src = "https://halfcourtshot.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1/js/half-court-shot.jsapp.mh.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">var hcs = new HalfCourtShot({ jersey: "matthewkosloski", shots: 3, goal: 'dribbble' });</script>                         

        </div><!-- end .footer-wrapper -->

            <div class="note-wrapper">

                <p id="note">&copy; 2013 Matthew Kosloski</p>

            </div><!-- end .note-wrapper-->

    </footer>
```

Comment: What exactly are "previous page" and "next page" supposed to link to?

Comment: To the second page of the posts.  I want to limit the first page to have 5 WP posts, and the continue the rest on a second page.

Answer (score 0):

in your admin settings > Reading (wp-admin/options-reading.php) change the posts per page count to 5

and for the links you're writing it wrong as per the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/posts_nav_link)

try this

```
<?php posts_nav_link('','<','>'); ?>
```

**UPDATE:**

You can add this if/else statement to show different on single or index

```
<?php if(is_single()) { // single-view navigation ?>

    <?php $posts = query_posts($query_string); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php previous_post_link('%link', '<'); ?>  | <?php next_post_link('%link', '>'); ?>

    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<?php } else { // archive view navigation ?>

        <?php posts_nav_link('','<','>'); ?>

<?php } ?>
```

see more help [here](http://digwp.com/2010/04/post-navigation-outside-loop/)

Comment: Does it have to be in a loop?  Because It's not showing up.  Maybe because it's in the footer-home.php?  I have different footers for different pages, I don't know if that's effecting it.  I posted my footer-home.php code above.

Comment: So on line 129 I would change the value of 1 to 5?

<input name="posts_per_page" type="number" step="1" min="1" id="posts_per_page" value="<?php form_option( 'posts_per_page' ); ?>" class="small-text" /> <?php _e( 'posts' ); ?

Comment: <?php previous_post_link(); ?> | <?php next_post_link(); ?> outputs the names of the posts.  I just need to do something like this :: http://codex.wordpress.org/Next_and_Previous_Links and I need to put it inside the code above as footer-home.php

Comment: @MatthewKosloski updated again. you have to run a string in the function in order to get customized text different than the default